# Log4j2 NoSQL Cassandra configuration in .properties file

Tags: cassandra, nosql, log4j2, apache-karaf

I'm trying to add an appender to Karaf 4.2, to log exceptions to Cassandra (DSE). My "org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg" file looks like this:

```
log4j2.rootLogger.appenderRef.cassandrass.ref = Cassandra
# Cassandra Appender
log4j2.appender.cass.type=NoSql
log4j2.appender.cass.name=Cassandra
```

but it fails with

```
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] ERROR : NoSQL provider not specified for appender [Cassandra]. Ignored FQCN: org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger
Null object returned for NoSql in Appenders. Ignored FQCN: org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger
Unable to locate appender "Cassandra" for logger config "root" Ignored FQCN: org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger
```

Almost every configuration example I find is in the xml format. Does anyone have a working example they can share? It is complaining "NoSQL provider not specified" which makes perfect sense. I just don't know how to configure the provider to be Cassandra

This is the guide I'm following: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CassandraAppender

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear in your post what you're trying to achieve. If you're attempting to configure logging for Cassandra, it won't work with Log4j.

Cassandra uses SLF4J with logback so you need to configure it accordingly. For details, see [Configuring logging in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/configuration/configLoggingLevels.html).

If you're using Log4j in your app, have a look at [Configuring Log4j with a properties file](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks - I should have been more clear: I'm using Karaf 4 which uses Pax Logging (and internally log4j2). I'm trying to add another appender that would log to Casandra. This is the guide I've been following, but the conf is in xml and I couldn't find a way to do it using properties: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CassandraAppender